# How to transform an point cloud at once in PostgreSQL with PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, transform, postgis, point-clouds, srid

I have an pointcloud which has an certain SRID. Now I want to transform the whole pointcloud using an select query into an different SRID (here: 4326 lat, lon). My first super inefficient approach is:

```
SELECT 
ST_X
( 
    ST_GeometryN( p , n ) 
) as lon , 
ST_Y
( 
    ST_GeometryN( p , n ) 
) as lat 
FROM 
ST_Ttransform
( 
    ST_SetSRID
    ( 
        ST_GeomFromText
        ( 
            'MULTIPOINT
            ( 
                10.0 20.0 30.0 , 40.0 50.0 60.0 , 70.0 80.0 90 
            )' -- three example 3d coordinates
        ) , 
        SRID_FROM -- current pointcloud srid
    ) , 
    SRID_TO -- desired pointcloud srid
) 
AS p 
CROSS JOIN 
generate_series
( 
    1 , 
    ST_NumGeometries( p ) 
) n
```

Is there any better way to achieve this tranformation? I need to transform approximately 10k - 100k points at once.

Comment: Where are stored  the point in input? in  postgis table? in  an external files?

Comment: In MATLAB, I pass them as a query using the Database Toolbox.

Comment: this mean that you have point  geometry  .. ?  and in which SR are stored in Matlab  ..  ? which coordinate have the point in matlab?

Comment: Yes, I have 3D coordinates in MATLAB with with various SRIDs which I want to transform in various SRIDs as well.

Comment: So you have a different SRID for each of the ca. 100k points? And want each to be transformed in a different SRID? Why do you import it as `Multipoint` from Matlab?

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen: Not in that sense. All source-points are in the same coordinate system (SRID_FROM). They all should be transferred into the other coordinate system (SRID_TO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope thats what you are aiming for. I get at least the same result.

I chose Pseudo Mercator (EPSG:3857) and transformed it to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)

```
SELECT ST_X(p) as lon , ST_Y(p) as lat 
FROM 
(SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(
                       ST_Transform(
                                    ST_GeomFromText( 
       'MULTIPOINT(10.0 20.0 30.0 , 40.0 50.0 60.0 , 70.0 80.0 90)', 3857) , 4326))).geom as p) gtab


         lon          |         lat
----------------------+----------------------
 8.98315284119521e-05 | 0.000179663056819876
 0.000359326113647809 | 0.000449157642049691
 0.000628820698883665 | 0.000718652227279505
(3 Zeilen)
```

But the question remains: Why import it as `MULTIPOINT`?

Comment: The answer is simple. I have no idea how to avoid a for loop where I transform a single coordinate. I want to transform them as one statement and have a return as two columns (lon,lat) as you did it. What would be the better way to achieve this? Your answer already simplifies my query. I'll check it soon.

Comment: Hm, maybe I don't really understand the problem. My answer transforms all your coordinates in one statement and returns lat an lon. What is missing?

Comment: Congratulations you've managed to reduce the query time from 47s to 0.35s by a factor of 134! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help!